# In Java, what is the better way to use Enums? With static constants or with constructors and off-file constants?

Tags: java, class, enums, constants

We are creating an enum for possible environments the user can login to. But in my team, we have a disagreement on what is the better way to proceed. I'm hoping to get some insight from the community, so that we can all learn.

1. The aim is to create an enum with environments (prod, staging, etc..)
2. Each environment, has a baseURL, a loginURLPostfix and a logoutURLPostfix.

What is the better way to go about this? And please explain why.

## Method 1

```
public enum Environment {
    Development,
    Production;

    //
    // Constants
    //

    private static String BASE_URL_STRING_PROD = "https://prodBaseURL.com";
    private static String BASE_URL_STRING_DEV = "https://devBaseURL.com";

    private static String LOGIN_SUFFIX = "/login";
    private static String LOGOUT_SUFFIX = "/logout";

    public String loginURLString() {
        return baseURL() + LOGIN_SUFFIX;
    }

    public String baseURL() {
        switch (this) {
            case Development: return BASE_URL_STRING_PROD;
            case Production: return BASE_URL_STRING_DEV;
            default: return REDIRECT_URI_PROD;
        }
    }
}
```

## Method 2

```
public enum Environment {
    Development(Constants.BASE_URL_STRING_DEV, Constants.LOGIN_SUFFIX),
    Production(Constants.BASE_URL_STRING_, Constants.LOGIN_SUFFIX);


    String baseURL;
    String loginURLSuffix;

    public Environment(String baseURL, String loginURLSuffix) {
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
        this.loginURL = loginURL
    }

    public String loginURLString() {
        return this.baseURL + Constants.LOGIN_SUFFIX;
    }
}


public class Constants {
    public static final String BASE_URL_STRING_PROD = "https://prodBaseURL.com";
    public static final String BASE_URL_STRING_DEV = "https://devBaseURL.com";

    public static final String LOGIN_SUFFIX = "/login";
    public static final String LOGOUT_SUFFIX = "/logout";
}
```

Edit: StackOverflow put the question on hold as an "opinion based" question. So my edit in order to clarify this is the following:

Is the difference between **Method 1** and **Method 2** purely opinion based?

Comment: I'd use the second way, except without the useless `Constants` class. You can pass the parameters directly to the constructors, so all the necessary information is contained inside your enum.

Comment: To store information about URLs per environment - 2nd option is the way to go. If You need to use sth like this: `switch (this) {` then it is a code smell that OO design is somehow wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like either approach for the properties you are trying to set.

What you have here is environment configuration in code, which is something that you should avoid as it requires a code change should any of these parameters change. Environment URL's would be best suited to a configuration file (XML, YAML, .properties, pick your poison) rather than hard-coded into your source code.